# AVR Eeprom Understanding

Tags: c, avr, eeprom

I have started to create a button counter and was successful in doing that then I shifted myself to reading and writing eeprom I tried to use the eeprom to read and write a single byte and was also successful in doing so, pretty basic stuff. Recently I tried to use the `eeprom_update_word` function which is a little confusing to me as I think doesn't work quite well I had tried but was successful can someone help me? Below is what I have written:

```
 // removed the standard header as they aren't displayed here!

void lcd_num (int);


int main(void)
{
    uint16_t c = 0;
    DDRD = 0x00;

    lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON);
    lcd_string(5, 0, "COUNTER");
    lcd_command(0xC5);
    // check if value has already been used/initialized...
    if (eeprom_read_word((uint16_t*)10) == UINT16_MAX)
    {
        // ...if not, init to 0
        eeprom_write_word((uint16_t*)10 , 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // ...if yes, read value back
        c = eeprom_read_word((uint16_t*)10);
    }
    lcd_data(c+48);

    while(1)
    {
        if( (PIND & 0x01) == 1 )
        {
            c++;
            lcd_command(0xC5);
            lcd_num(c);
            eeprom_update_word((uint16_t*)10, c);
            while( (PIND & 0x01) == 1 );
        }
        if((PIND & 0x02) == 1)
        {
            eeprom_write_word((uint16_t*)10,0);
            c = eeprom_read_word((uint16_t*)10);
            while((PIND & 0x02) == 1);
        }
    }
}



void lcd_num(int n){
    lcd_data((n/1000)+48);
    n %= 1000;

    lcd_data((n/100)+48);
    n %= 100;

    lcd_data((n/10)+48);
    n %= 10;

    lcd_data(n+48);
}
            void lcd_num(int n){
            lcd_data((n/1000)+48);
            n %= 1000;

            lcd_data((n/100)+48);
            n %= 100;

            lcd_data((n/10)+48);
            n %= 10;

            lcd_data(n+48);
        }
```

Can I ask for another favour here? I want to use a manual button to erase the eeprom so that I may not run out of space I have tried this but this doesn't work. Am i doing this correct ??

Comment: do you mean `eeprom_update_word` (used in the code) or `epprom_update_byte` (mentioned in explanation) ?

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry I have mistakenly typed eeprom_update_byte in the explanation it was supposed to be eeprom_update_word as mentioned in the code

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Are you aware that you can [edit] your question? There is a small link on the right side below your question.

Comment: Are you sure that the port reads "1" when the button is down? Are there some pull-down resistor?

Comment: Yes , with this setup (code) the button reads one when pressed when reads zero when not pressed with no debounce at all.The first button works flawlessly you can try out yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your counter value gets overwritten on each restart. You need to do some kind of check, whether the EEPROM location was already initialized (default EEPROM content is all 0xFF).

```
// check if value has already been used/initialized...
if (eeprom_read_word((uint16_t*)10) == UINT16_MAX)
{
    // ...if not, init to 0
    eeprom_write_word((uint16_t*)10 , 0);
} 
else 
{
    // ...if yes, read value back
    c = eeprom_read_word((uint16_t*)10);
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks very much I had tried to use what I have written above but it doesn't even compile how great of you to check and solve the problem in one go.Thank you very much works perfectly..

Answer (score 2):

Since *all* of your program is executed when powered on, this lines will run, too:

```
uint16_t c = 0;
// unrelated lines ...
eeprom_write_word((uint16_t*)10 ,c);
```

And they will overwrite the value you stored there before.